# Simple Slider with Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm trying to get a content slider working. We are using **Kendo UI** as a UI framework for the application that I'm working on, and I'm not too keen or writing my own **jQuery slider** or using one of the self.

I was wondering if anyone has tried using Kendo UI to build a simple content slider. Like http://www.sequencejs.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. :) Your question is very general, and the answer would be "probably". Try to make it more specific: What have you tried so far, what are you concerned about, is there a problem in particular with this framework that you would like to have answered?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but I'm just trying to get a basic content slider to work. I haven't tried anything because I'm not even sure if it's worth my time to try it out. 

I was wondering if anyone else had tried it before.